# how to make efficiently large sparse matrix in python?

Tags: python, performance, numpy, matrix, variable-assignment

1.
i try to make a numpy array with shape:(6962341, 268148), type: np.uint8

2.
i have the data consist of [x1,x2,x3,x4], [x2,x1], [x4,x5,x3]...

3.
i want to assign array[x1,x2] += 1, array[x1,x3] += 1, array[x1,x4] += 1, array[x2,x3] += 1, ...

4.
so i have tried a function of the following structure.

---

```
import numpy as np
from itertools import combinations

base_array = np.zeros((row_size, col_size), dtype=np.uint8))

for each_list in data:
  for (x,y) in list(combinations(each_list,2)):
    if x>y:
      base_array[y,x] += 1
    else:
      base_array[x,y] += 1
```

---

it basically compute the upper triangle of a matrix and i will use the upper triangle value. also you can think this is similar to make the base matrix A for co-occurrence matrix. but this function is too slow and i think it is possible to make faster. 
What should i do?

Comment: What is your data `x1, x2, ...`types?

Comment: my data consist of only integer and each list is not include same element

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your data is integers (since they represent rows and columns) or you can hash your data `x1, x2, ...` into `1, 2, ...` integers, here is a fast solution:

```
#list of pairwise combinations in your data
comb_list = []
for each_list in data:
  comb_list += list(combinations(each_list,2))

#convert combination int to index (numpy is 0 based indexing)
comb_list = np.array(comb_list) - 1

#make array with flat indices
flat = np.ravel_multi_index((comb_list[:,0],comb_list[:,1]),(row_size,col_size))

#count number of duplicates for each index using np.bincount
base_array = np.bincount(flat,None,row_size*col_size).reshape((row_size,col_size)).astype(np.uint8)
```

sample data:

```
[[1, 2, 3, 4], [2, 1], [4, 5, 3, 4]]
```

Corresponding output:

```
[[0 1 1 1 0]
 [1 0 1 1 0]
 [0 0 0 2 0]
 [0 0 1 1 1]
 [0 0 1 1 0]]
```

EDIT: corresponding to explanation in comments:

```
data=[[1, 2, 3, 4], [2, 1], [4, 5, 3, 4]]
base_array = np.zeros((len(data), np.max(np.amax(data))), dtype=np.uint8)

for i, each_list in enumerate(data):
  for j in each_list:
    base_array[i, j-1] = 1
```

Output:

```
[[1 1 1 1 0]
 [1 1 0 0 0]
 [0 0 1 1 1]]
```

Comment: Thanks! but... i don't understand yet. i want that the shape of output equal to data.shape. Could you explain more about it in detail?

Comment: @HyunNow Your data _**i have the data consist of [x1,x2,x3,x4], [x2,x1], [x4,x5,x3]...**_ does not have a shape. It is a list of lists. Please provide sample input and output data so I can adjust accordingly. Currently, the `base_array` is a 2D array of shape `(xn, xn)` where `xn` is the maximum integer in your data.

Comment: input_list = [[0,1],[0,2,3],[2,4]] then output_array = [[1,1,0,0,0],[1,0,1,1,0],[0,0,1,0,1]]. finally, i want to calculate np.dot(output_array.T, output_array) for co-occurrence matrix

Comment: Please elaborate on how you create an `output_array` of shape `(3,5)` from your input data. This output is not inline with your provided code. It is unclear to me how you want it to be. Usually co-occurrence matrix is a NxN matrix with element (i,j)=# of times i and j happen in the same list in data. This is what my code creates. If this is not what you are looking for please explain it in more details of how exactly each element (i,j) in output is calculated so we can help better. From what it looks, you are looking for dummy vector representation of your lists in data. Is that correct?

Comment: shape of output_array is (len(input_list), max_len(list in input_list)) and consist of 0 or 1. i think you understand that, dummy vector! i thought that firstly make output_array and calculate co-occurrence array = np.dot(output_array.T, output_array). then final output_array is square. my code in question return final_output_array.

Comment: Your `final_output_array` in your code is not what you are describing in your comment. Nonetheless, I will add this comment's solution to the post too. Hope it help. And I am assuming by `max_len(list in input_list)` you mean `max_value(list in input_list)`, otherwise, I do not understand it and the presented sample output would not be correct either.